# Setting up GDB pretty printing in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I tried to set up GDB pretty printing (for easier work with standard containers) according to [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5713387/246337). Instead of using python pretty printers code from svn I used the ones that [ship with ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt#comment28302485_5713387). After going through the rest of the process I ended up with the following error message when launching gdb:

```
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/nietaki/gdb_printers/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 54
    raise ValueError, "Cannot find type %s::%s" % (str(orig), name)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
/home/nietaki/.gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

After looking a little deeper into the problem I found out the root cause lays deeper - [Python 3 used in gdb is incompatible with libstdc++ pretty printers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1258642).

Does anyone have a functional workaround for that? For now I'm stuck with the (also useful, but not as functional) helpers from Dan Marinescu: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF

Comment: I have two questions: First, is Ask Ubuntu the right place, and why? Second, isn't this is a bug of the application? In both cases, it is off-topic!

Comment: How is this off-topic? I linked a confirmed, high importance bug from the **Ubuntu** launchpad that causes my problem and asked for a workaround. If anyone using 13.10 got this working I could certainly use their solution. I checked with a friend who is on Gentoo and this issue doesn't affect them.

Comment: There is an uncommitted patch to make the printers work with Python 3 at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-10/msg00243.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest fix seems to be to set up the pretty printers as normal but then convert `printers.py` to python3 using 2to3:

```
2to3 printers.py -w
```

I've only tested it briefly, but it seems to work fine.